# What does "native_blocked" status mean in a jrockit JVM

Tags: java, jvm, deadlock, jrockit

I have a server process that seems hung, but there is no Java-level deadlock when I do a thread dump. There's only an Open lock chain with one of the critical threads in it (explains why the entire process "died").

At the "open" end of the chain, is this thread which is "native_blocked", however there is not much more information as to why it is "blocked".

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Oracle JRockit(R) (build R28.1.3-11-141760-1.6.0_24-20110301-1432-linux-x86_64, compiled mode)
```

Can someone familiar with the JRockit JVM provide a little color? Thanks in advance:

```
"unnamed" id=44967 idx=0x808 tid=19423 prio=5 alive, suspended (java), native_blocked, daemon
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.profMonitorContendedEntered(Ljava/lang/Object;)V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1163)
    ^-- Holding lock: com/mycompany/apps/myapp/SomeClass@0x2659027c8[recursive]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:1005)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnter(Locks.java:2179)
```

Comment: Examining this a little closer, it looks like the thread is also "suspended". could this be related? Why would it be suspended in the first place though if there is no Thread.suspend in my code?

Comment: I'm suspecting this has to do with someone else having a debug session live on it, and he/she has paused the thread(s). I'll try to confirm if that's the case...... (embarrassed)